# Jump of Line while Reading words in a txt File with Scanner

Tags: java, file, lines

I'm reading words in a Scanner, but i need to know if the Scanner changes to the following line. this is for a Progress Bar(counting Lines).
Can you help me? Here is my code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{Alpha}]+");
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
               while (sc.hasNext()) {
               sc.useDelimiter(pattern);
               long totalLines = countLines(f);//Method that count Lines
               System.out.println("Reading " + totalLines + "Lines...");
               word = sc.next();//here i need to know if the scanner jumps to next Line or not.
```

Comment: why dont you try hasNextLine() and nextLine() methods available in Scanner class?

Comment: because i'm reading Words. Scanner Doesn`t Tell me if the next word is in another line or not. i need to know that.

Comment: you can take one line at a time, split it with space and then can count words in that.

Comment: Thats better, can i take a Line and Scan it? Because I'm using a Pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [hasNextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()) and [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) methods available in Scanner class.

iterate over lines.For each line,split that using space and count number of words in that.

Comment: i'm reading Words. Scanner Doesn`t Tell me if the next word is in another line or not. i need to know that.